# Python regex to find words, which also excludes particular words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming. I've searched this site and Google, but can't seem to resolve this issue. I'm finding similar topics, but still can't figure this out...

I have a text file containing a very large list of words. The words are all numbered and also categorized by 'noun', 'adjective' or 'verb'.

I'd like to extract the words from this list, but exclude numbers and the following three words, 'noun', 'adjective' and 'verb.'

I know I need to use the caret character, but can't seem to make it work.

```
import re
import os

textFile = open('/Users/MyComputer/wordList.txt')

textFileContent = textFile.read()

wordFinder = re.compile(r"""
[a-z]+ # finds words
[^noun|adjective|verb] # THIS IS WRONG
""", re.VERBOSE | re.I)

regexResults = wordFinder.findall(textFileContent)
```

Comment: "I know I need to use the caret character .." because you've read it is a logical `not`, right? But it's only to negate *character classes*. You made it check for "not an n, not an o, not an u, not a pipe" and so on - but only *one* of these characters. It does not work on 'words'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

with open('wordList.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search("^(?!noun|adjective|verb|\d)", line):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which could give this regex expression:

```
[^a-z](?!noun|adjective|verb)([a-z]+)
```